# Adding the dba SE site as a migration option

Tags: discussion, migration

Maybe there should an option to migrate question to the the [dba site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

[Related review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/13782)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past 90 days, we have migrated:

- 25 questions to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- 5 questions to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- 4 questions to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- 2 questions to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- 1 question to each of [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Only SO has enough migrations to justify a migration path. There are none to DBA, so a migration path is not warranted. Flag if you think a question should be migrated.

This question seems too low-quality or at least borderline-quality for migration anyway. I fear that there is too little information about the asker's setup to answer. There were no answers anyway, so the asker can just reask the question on another site.